# How to enable "Additional Information" window in Visual Studio 2022 during creating a new project from a custom template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, vsix, project-template

I create a VSIX package which contains a project template.
The VSIX package compiles and installs as a Visual Studio 2022 extension without any issues.
Also, it appears as one of the templates when the new project is created:
[image: Custom console app project template]

The main problem is that the .Net version (not .Net Framework) can't be changed during the creating process as the "Additional Information" window can't be invoked. The "Create" button appears instead of the "Next" button:
[image: The "Create" button appears]

The template project has the TargetFramework `net6.0`.
My goal is to create the template which should allow choosing TargetFramework during the creating process. For example:
[image: Configure new project]

[image: Additional information window]

I used this article for development process with no success:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template?view=vs-2022

What was missing?